# Required Property Missing, though it is in the source

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I'm trying to use the Facebook Comments Box on a page that is particular to the page and not the website as a whole.

> Required Property Missing  og:title is required. The Like Plugin will only generate one-line stories unless this property is provided.
>   Required Property Missing  og:type is required. The Like Plugin will only generate one-line stories unless this property is provided.
>   Required Property Missing  og:url is required. The Like Plugin will only generate one-line stories unless this property is provided.
>   Required Property Missing  og:image is required. The Like Plugin will only generate one-line stories unless this property is provided.
>   Required Property Missing  fb:app_id is required. The Like Plugin will only generate one-line stories unless this property is provided.

The metadata from my page is this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="I Signed the Law School Transparency Petition"/>  
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.lawschooltransparency.com/LSTPetition"/>  
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.lawschooltransparency.com/wp-content/themes/LST2011/images/LST_banner2.png"/>  
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Law School Transparency"/>  
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>  
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="237357506317071"/>
```

Linter: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lawschooltransparency.com%2FLSTPetition%2F
Live Page: http://www.lawschooltransparency.com/LSTPetition/

I'm honestly stumped. The HTML is otherwise well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings from the linter refer only to the like button, not the comment box (which seems to run flawless). It's weird though that you get those warnings, but I somehow remember that I had that too a while ago, can't recall though how I got rid of them. 
I suggest anyway that you try to insert yourself as admin and click the like button (to confirm the administration rights). Might help...

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1234567890"/>
```

You have to change 1234567890 to your facebook id for sure!
The warnings may also appear when the app id is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

The curious thing is that the errors have to do with the comment box despite it saying it's the like button. When I comment, I get the default settings from my home page cobbled together by the Facebook crawler. In other words, when I comment and publish it to my Facebook wall, it says "Kyle commented on lawschooltransparency.com" and then provides our description for the website not the one I set in this metadata.

Comment: As an additional confirmation, I removed the like button code and it did not change the linter output.

Comment: I fixed it but have no idea how/why.

Comment: On further investigating your code I can see that you are using two different app ids. The one in the meta tags is different to the one in the javascript, might be a reason. Another reason for it might be that you are loading the javascript before the <div class="fb-root"></div>, as far as I know it's a good habit to place javascript code at the bottom of the page anyway!

Comment: Also try using the xfbml version instead of the html5!